# Do you ever need typename and template together?

Tags: c++, parsing, language-lawyer, dependent-type, c++23

I'm curious whether there is ever a case where `typename` on its own is not sufficiently disambiguating.
When the `typename` disambiguator is used, then the following *qualified-id* must be a type.
For example, in the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct foo;

template <typename T, typename U>
void bar() {
    typename foo<T>::mystery<0> x;
}
```

The standard requires the use of `template` for the dependent name `mystery`, but I am not aware of a parsing ambiguity if you omit it. The `<0` cannot possibly mean "less than zero", because `typename` says we must produce a type, and expressions never yield types.

[GCC compiles this, but clang doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/5rKr1fdof) and produces the error:

```
error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'mystery' as a dependent template name
    typename foo<T>::mystery<0> x;
                     ^
                     template
```

Is my understanding correct here, i.e. `template` is required by the standard, but not necessary for the compiler?

#### Update

It seems like there are some relaxations in C++23 for just the terminal name `mystery`, which may allow omitting `typename` here, but those are unrelated to GCC's implementation. GCC 10 in C++98 mode allows this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void bar() {
    typename foo<T>::mystery<T>::surprise<T>::shock<T> x;
}
```

I was unable to find this feature in the [changelogs](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html).

Even with arbitrary nesting, it's obvious that `template` is unnecessary here, because until we parse the *id-expression* of the *declarator*, every `<` has to be a template pointy bracket.

Comment: Good question. `<` can't be parsed as the less operator in this context, thus why does clang require `template`: `typename foo<T>::template mystery<0> x;`?

Comment: It is the same issue we discussed recently in your other question: Without `template` disambiguation there is generally no way, or at least no easy way, to tell where the nested name ends because `<` may be the less-than operator in an expression in a non-type template argument. In your specific case there is no difficulty in figuring this out, but in general there is. The standard simply doesn't make any special exceptions for these easy cases.

Comment: @273K https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3 is the relevant section I believe. The standard doesn't consider `typename` to have an effect on pointy bracket disambiguation from the looks of it.

Comment: @JanSchultke Actually that is saying that your specific example doesn't require `template` because of the `typename`: Because of the `typename` introduction this is a [_typename-specifier_](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier) and it is the terminal name of that typename-specifier, so it is a [_type-only context_](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-4) and therefore `<` is assumed to introduce a template argument list per https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3.4. That was changed for C++23 with https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html.

Comment: @user17732522 does terminal name mean that this relaxation only applies to the last name? Would you need `typename foo<T>::template mystery<0>::surprise` ?

Comment: @JanSchultke Yes, that's what the restriction "_other than a nested-name-specifier_" seems to imply and would avoid the issue that a second `<` could be a less-than.

Comment: @JanSchultke By the way _terminal name_ is defined in https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#prim.id.unqual-2.sentence-3 and the _component names_ of different constructs are defined where they are introduced, e.g. in https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-3 for _typename-specifier_.

Answer (score 0):

In short, Clang doesn't implement all relaxations yet and GCC is too permissive in letting you omit `template`.
A lot of the rules surrounding scope, name lookup, dependent names, etc. have been massively overhauled by [P1787: Declarations and where to find them](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html).

As things stand, [[temp.names] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3) states:

> A `<` is interpreted as the delimiter of a *[template-argument-list](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument-list)* if it follows a name that is not a conversion-function-id and
>
> - [...]
> - that is a terminal name in a *[using-declarator](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#nt:using-declarator)*, in a *[declarator-id](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl.general#nt:declarator-id)*, or in a **[type-only context](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#def:context,type-only) other than a *[nested-name-specifier](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:nested-name-specifier)***.

In the declaration:

> ```cpp
> typename foo<T>::mystery<0> x;
> ```

`mystery` is in the [type-only context](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#def:context,type-only) of a *[typename-specifier](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#nt:typename-specifier)*, so the `<0>` is interpreted as a *[template-argument-list](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument-list)*, not as `<` and `>` operators.
The `template` keyword can be safely omitted here, however, Clang does not yet implement this.

#### GCC allows omitting `template` where it should be mandatory

GCC takes it a step too far by allowing:

> ```cpp
> typename foo<T>::mystery<T>::surprise<T>::shock<T> x;
> ```

Not only does it support all relaxations long before C++23 where they take effect, this declaration also isn't valid.

- `typename foo<T>::mystery<T>` can be parsed as a *[typename-specifier](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#nt:typename-specifier)* where `template` before `mystery` is optional
- `surprise<T>::` is not valid because `surprise` is the terminal name in a *[nested-name-specifier](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:nested-name-specifier)* and those are excluded from the relaxation (see above)

Besides the standardese, GCC is intuitively going too far because after `typename foo<T>::mystery<T>`, one could say that "the `typename` disambiguator has been used up".